# Отобразить текстовую таблицу

Tags: java, android, gui, recyclerview

Я только недавно стал разбираться с программированием Android и поэтому, скорее всего, просто не понимаю его идеологии.

Стоит у меня простая задача:

1. отобразить таблицу c текстовыми данными
2. нарисовать сетку таблицы
3. отобразить заголовки колонок таблицы
4. при щелчке на caption заголовка в код должно приходить событие.

Сразу уточню - таблица узкая и в экран влазит.

Что я сделал:

1. Отобразил таблицу на основании RecyclerView с правильным адаптером. Макет получился такой

   ```xml
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:name="com.mycompany.DetectFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
       android:paddingStart="0dp"
       android:paddingEnd="0dp"
       app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
       tools:context=".DetectFragment"
       tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_detect_item" />
   ```

   `fragment_detect_item.xml`

   ```xml
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/detectItem"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
           android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/text_margin"
           android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
           android:maxLines="1"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Сетку нарисовал при помощи двух `DividerItemDecoration`.

   Тут возникло первое недопонимание: вертикальные линии рисовались на всю высоту RecyclerView, а не только на ту часть, где были данные. Проблема решилась переопределением метода `onDraw` у декоратора и установкой правильной высоты. Логику стандартного поведения, как и то, почему `DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL)` рисует **вертикальные** линии, а `DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)` **горизонтальные** линии так и не понял.
3. Заголовки колонок стал рисовать на основании модели "липких" заголовков вот [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327350/5376639), с модификацией, что у меня заголовок всегда один. Пока удалось вывести только прямоугольник другого цвета.

Скорее всего и эту проблему решу, но мне не нравится сам принцип: для решения элементарнейшей, на мой взгляд задачи, такой объем телодвижений. Я точно двигаюсь в правильном направлении или есть гораздо более простой путь?

Например, Студия показывает компонент GridView. По-идее, это то, что мне нужно. Но он лежит на вкладке Legacy

Comment: А Вам точно нужна таблица? В мобаиле (кроме экселя) я таблиц что-то вообще не помню. Может, проблема в том, что ui-подход десктопа на автомате потащили, а в мобильном дизайне лучше инфу другим способом отобразить?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov нужно отобразить пять колонок в каждой 3-5 цифры. Причем данные нужно отображать по мере появления по принципу "последний сверху". Я, конечно, не уверен, но таблица напрашивается сама собой.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Опять таки, календарь в виде таблицы никого не смущает?

Comment: Действительно, календарь пожалуй тоже можно считать таблицей)
Если я правильно понимаю, то вам нужно отобразить приходящие в режиме реального времени данные (например, с какого-то датчика). я бы сделал обычный линейный список (вида 123 | 312 | ... | 0 | 12). С линеными списками обычно работать проще, чем с таблицей. Вместо стики-хедеров можно просто список разместить под вьюхой, отображающей заголовки (если хочется, чтобы заголовки прятались при скролле - используйте CollapsingToolbar, это куда проще стики-хедеров). Но это конечно сильно зависит от задачи